# GA4: Trying to compare the 'Average engagement time' for different events created by me

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to increase the 'Average engagement time' of the users of my website, by modifying the format and appearance of the pages, and by using GA4 (completely new for me).

Into the JavaScript code of the pages, I created different GA4 events for the different modifications of the format each time the page loads. For instance:

```
gtag('event', 'modification_03');
```

However, I do not know how to browse the results of the tests. I access on Google Analytics: Reports > Engagement > Overview, and I click "Add comparison".

In the "Build comparison" column of the right, I select

- Dimension = Event Label
- Match Type = exactly matches

However, the "Value" field is grey ("No recent values"), and I can not select the 'modification_03' value.

I do not know if I am doing something wrong.